# Unsuccessful GET request through ESP8266

Tags: php, http, nginx, esp8266, at-command

I am trying to send a GET request to a PHP file uploaded on web by ESP8266, but I want do it directly by serial monitor. Every thing is right and the GET request sends correctly but the PHP file does not execute.

When I try to call the PHP file in browser and run http://readsensor.epizy.com/esp_post.php?temperature=11&humidity=11 it executes and data changes correctly on web.

Here is my serial monitor

```
AT+CIPSTART="TCP","readsensor.epizy.com",80

CONNECT

OK
AT+CIPSEND=85

OK
> 
Recv 85 bytes

SEND OK

+IPD,1099:HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Sun, 15 Jul 2018 12:59:01 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 870
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache

<html><body><script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js" ></script> 
<script>function toNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d) 
{e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return e}function toHex(){for(var d= 
[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array? 
arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;f<d.length;f++)e+= 
(16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);return e.toLowerCase()}var 
a=toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),b=toNumbers
("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),c=toNumbers  
("248813c2e30a32e656e03e29a770b794");document.cookie="__test=
"+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+"; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; 
path=/"; location.href="http://readsensor.epizy.com/esp_post.php? 
temperature=40&humidity=40&i=1";</script><noscript>This site requires 
Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser 
with Javascript support</noscript></body></html>CLOSED
```

Because of this part of response

> This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support

I checked my web browser to enable script and even changed it but still I facing this error.

My server is NGINX. Is there a problem with the server?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the error message.

> This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support

Then look at the code that is returned by the server:

> ```
> document.cookie="__test="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+"; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT;
> ```

It sets a cookie…

> ```
> location.href="http://readsensor.epizy.com/esp_post.php?
> ```
>
> temperature=40&humidity=40&i=1";

… then redirects the browser.

So either:

- You are requesting a URL which isn't `http://readsensor.epizy.com/esp_post.php`, and then the JavaScript doesn't run, and you never request the PHP *or*
- The PHP checks to see if a cookie is set, and if it is not, it outputs JavaScript to set it, and then redirect to run the script again.

If the problem is the former, then you just need to change your code to request the first URL in the first place.

If it is the latter, then you'll need to send the cookie data. You might be able to hard code that into your program, or you might need to parse the response to extract the right values for the cookie from the script.

Comment: If i want to set a cookie, would the cookie name be __test? What value should I set?